# Scaffold displaying a bar at the bottom that is not meant to be there

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My Scaffold displays a bar at the bottom like this: [image]
that I did not put there (I know that it is the scaffold because when I remove it the bar is gone. but I cant do this without scaffold) this is my code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text('Scaffold Bar test'),
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 88,
            child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
              return Container(
                height: 40.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.orange,
              );
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` in the `Scaffold`.

And use `MediaQuery.removePadding` with `removeTop: true` to remove unnecessary padding at top of the `ListView.builder`.

Use `Expanded` instead of getting height from `MediaQuery`.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeTop: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text('Scaffold Bar test'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 40.0,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.orange,
                );
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```